# Pytorch2.0 Assertion Error of 3D convolutional layers

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch

I'm trying to add two convolutional layers in my neural network, one for channel expansion, another for information aggregation.
Now,I've got some sequential data that looks like (128,96,3,3,3,100), where 128 is the batchsize,96 the timesteps of a sequence,100 the feature dimension,and (3,3,3) indicates we use 27 neighbourhood information.
Here's the code in pytorch:

```
class GPT(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, config,
                 dim=100,
                 bias=False,):
        super().__init__()
        self.fe_1=nn.Conv3d(dim, dim*3, kernel_size=1,stride=1, bias=bias)
        self.fe_2=nn.Conv3d(dim*3, dim, kernel_size=3,stride=1, bias=bias)
        
        self.transformer = nn.ModuleDict(dict(...)
    def forward(self, idx, targets=None):
        device = idx.device
        b, t, h, w, l, c = idx.shape
        assert t <= self.config.block_size, f"Cannot forward sequence of length {t}, block size is only {self.config.block_size}"
        pos = torch.arange(0, t, dtype=torch.long, device=device).unsqueeze(0) # shape (1, t)

        
        idx = idx.permute(0,1,5,2,3,4)
        idx = idx.reshape((-1,c,h,w,l))#(12288,100,3,3,3)
        out = self.fe_1(idx)
        out = self.fe_2(out)
        idx = out.reshape((b,t,c))


        # forward the transformer itself
        tok_emb = self.transformer.wte(idx) 
        pos_emb = self.transformer.wpe(pos)
        x = self.transformer.drop(tok_emb + pos_emb)
```

To match the requirement of nn.Conv3d, I reshape the input data in forward function from (128,96,3,3,3,100) to (12288,100,3,3,3) to get the feature dimension in the second position.
Though I've checked the input and output shape of each layer and was sure they are all correct, I got troubles as follow:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/xxx/nanoGPT-master/nanoGPT-master/traincopy_0726_725_cnn.py", line 334, in <module>
    scaler.scale(loss).backward()
  File "/home/xxx/.conda/envs/torchreborn/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/_tensor.py", line 487, in backward
    torch.autograd.backward(
  File "/home/xxx/.conda/envs/torchreborn/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/autograd/__init__.py", line 200, in backward
    Variable._execution_engine.run_backward(  # Calls into the C++ engine to run the backward pass
  File "/home/xxx/.conda/envs/torchreborn/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/autograd/function.py", line 274, in apply
    return user_fn(self, *args)
  File "/home/xxx/.conda/envs/torchreborn/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/_functorch/aot_autograd.py", line 2348, in backward
    out = call_compiled_backward()
  File "/home/xxx/.conda/envs/torchreborn/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/_functorch/aot_autograd.py", line 2324, in call_compiled_backward
    out = call_func_with_args(
  File "/home/xxx/.conda/envs/torchreborn/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/_functorch/aot_autograd.py", line 1247, in call_func_with_args
    out = normalize_as_list(f(args))
  File "/home/xxx/.conda/envs/torchreborn/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/_dynamo/eval_frame.py", line 209, in _fn
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/xxx/.conda/envs/torchreborn/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/_inductor/compile_fx.py", line 248, in run
    return model(new_inputs)
  File "/tmp/torchinductor_xxx/qx/cqxoopct2ddmpulx7yvt4x3iokeyymbcilpaq5z6gnphb3z6p6j5.py", line 2252, in call
    assert_size_stride(buf303, (12288, 300, 3, 3, 3), (8100, 1, 2700, 900, 300))
AssertionError: expected size 300==300, stride 27==1 at dim=1
```

I've tried to add only one of these two layers every time, and the code runs well. Once they are put together, I will meet the same error as above. And it's clearly that the mistake is root in the convolutional layer, but I don't know the meaning of  `(8100, 1, 2700, 900, 300)` in output error message`assert_size_stride(buf303, (12288, 300, 3, 3, 3), (8100, 1, 2700, 900, 300))`, therefore I have no idea about how to solve the problem.I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to solve this.

Comment: Your code seems ok... Did you try without the mixed precision?

Comment: While I have a GradScaler, I 'm setting dtype to torch.float32 in whole process, so GradScaler has not been used:`dtype = 'float32'` ,`scaler = torch.cuda.amp.GradScaler(enabled=(dtype == 'float16'))`. Don't know if it can be seen as fixed precision?

Comment: You may try with the vanilla `loss.backward()` to see if it is a problem from the scaler

Comment: Hi, I've tried to run the code without Scaler, but unfortunately got the same error... bad news. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is there anything else that looks wrong?